# How to Route Yii2 REST API module

Tags: yii2, restful-url

am building Yii2 REST API for the first timw and following some documentation online I came up with the below, but after setup i got 404 error and I don't know where this error is coming from, maybe a problem with my REST URL or problem my my API module. Any help on this would be appreciated

```
Controller class
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

class CountryController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Country'; 
}



Model Class

<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "country".
 *
 * @property string $code
 * @property string $name
 * @property int $population
 */
class Country extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'country';
    }
    
    public static function primaryKey(){ 
        return ['code']; 
        
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['code', 'name'], 'required'],
            [['population'], 'integer'],
            [['code'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 52],
            [['code'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'code' => 'Code',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'population' => 'Population',
        ];
    }
}

Config file

<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'api\modules\v1\controllers',
    'modules' => [      
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@api/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module',
        ],

    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        ],

        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],

       'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v1/country'],
                    'pluralize' => false,
                    'tokens' => ['{id}' => 'id:\\\\w+'],
                ],                  
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

When I try to send a get request to `http://localhost/country` from postman i got 404 i also tried `http://localhost/v1/country` but got 404 too, what i'm i doing wrong below is the directory sturcture of my api module

[image]

updated tying error in my question I visited `http://localhost/country` not `http://localhost/countries` below is a postman screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying `.../countries` when you've set `$pluralize` property to `false`?

Comment: @Michal Hynčica I made a typing error, i have updated it and also uploaded a screensho from postman. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the requests to correct domain? Your postman screenshots uses url `https://checkstall.com/...` but based on this https://checkstall.com/debug/default/view?tag=62f15cfe48c1d&panel=router it seems it's frontend part running on that domain and not the api part.

Comment: @Michal Hynčica yeah that's correct the front end part is running on the domain but the full app also on the domain, and i newly created the APi to eun on the domain but not sure how to configure this...

Comment: Well, because the domain is pointed into `frontend/web` folder its index.php is processed and the application is run with frontend's config. The api config is not even loaded. If you want to have frontend and api on same domain probably the most easy thing to do is to implement api as module inside the frontend app instead of making it independent app.

Comment: @Michal Hynčica your suggestion worked thanks